# NodeJs check username and password return null

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to check the entered username and password stored in a database.
My solution is not correct and I think there might be something better than my code.

Here it is thus far:

```
function login (username, password, callback) {
    var query = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

    connection.query(query, [username], function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (results.length === 0) return callback();
        var user = results[0];

        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
            return callback();
        }

        callback(null,   {
            id:          user.id.toString(),
        });

    });
}
app.get('/salam', function (req, res) {
    var username = 'mahdi';
    var originalPassword = 'a';

    login(username , originalPassword,function (callback) {
        console.log(callback);
    });
});
```

In my code, `console.log(callback);` returns null, but usernames and passwords are correct. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are already setting first parameter of callback as a NULL? `callback(**null**, { id: user.id.toString(), });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your success `callback` function, you are having 2 arguments but in error callback, only one argument.

In `error` and `success` case, value of first parameter will always be `null` and in `if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {` case, value of first argument will be `undefined` as there is no value being passed as argument.

**Suggestion:**  Use first argument as `Boolean`(`false` or `true`) and based on the value, handle the callback.

```js
function login(username, password, callback) {
  var query = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

  connection.query(query, [username], function(err, results) {
    if (err) return callback(false);
    if (results.length === 0) return callback();
    var user = results[0];

    if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
      return callback(false);
    }
    callback(true, {
      id: user.id.toString(),
    });

  });
}
app.get('/salam', function(req, res) {
  var username = 'mahdi';
  var originalPassword = 'a';

  login(username, originalPassword, function(success, value) {
    if (success) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: It won't always be `null`: there are two places in the OP's code (and one place in yours) where the function is called with no arguments, so then `callback` will be `undefined`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Updated.. Missed that part ;)

Comment: @Rayon Thanks, problem resolved sir :) wait to me for accept that

Comment: @mahdipishguy – I'm glad it helped mate! _Happy Coding_

Comment: @Rayon hi, could you help me on this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/q/38794164/6599627  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be, because you didn't pass anything in callback. Change like this :

```
function login (username, password, callback) {
    var query = "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE username = ?";

    connection.query(query, [username], function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        if (results.length === 0) return callback(null, false);
        var user = results[0];

        if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
            return callback(null, false);
        }

        callback(null,   true, {
            id:          user.id.toString(),
        });

    });
}
app.get('/check', function (req, res) {
    var username = 'mahdi';
    var originalPassword = 'a';

    login(username , originalPassword,function (err, result, id) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
        console.log(id);
    });
});
```

`result` is for finding out `true|false` of action. And `id` means when `result` is true

Also `err` for `callback` is needed to error handling

Comment: If you don't pass anything (which is the case in two places) the argument will be `undefined`,  not `null`. But in what I assume it's the success case the OP's code explicitly passes `null`.

Comment: @Ebrahim Pasbani  +1 Thanks  Ebrahim agha