# Asynchronously get generated array on function and pass it out of the box

Tags: javascript, node.js

## Problem resolved on [Asynchronously solution to check data from database kinds of loop clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806097/asynchronously-solution-to-check-data-from-database-kinds-of-loop-clause)

with this below code i can generate simple array as jsonArray into `checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet` function, but i can't pass it out of that to send inside client,

with `socket.emit('syncContacts', accountNumbers)` i get `[]` result on `accountNumbers`, but into `if (success) {` statement array successful created and pushed into `accountNumbers` array

```
socket.on('syncContacts', function (data) {
    var accountNumbers = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet(data[i].mobileNumber, function (success) {
            if (success) {
                accountNumbers.push({ewalletNumber: this.mobileNumber});
                console.log(accountNumbers);
            }
        }.bind({mobileNumber: data[i].mobileNumber}));
    }
    console.log(accountNumbers);

    socket.emit('syncContacts', accountNumbers);
});

function checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet(mobileNumber, callback) {
    var mobileNumber = mobileNumber.substr(1, mobileNumber.length);

    var query = "SELECT id FROM userEwallets WHERE ewalletNumber LIKE '%" + mobileNumber + "'";
    connection.query(query, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(false);

        if (results.length === 0)
            return callback(false);
        else {
            return callback(true);
        }

    });
}
```

## Updated after post comments:

```
socket.on('syncContacts', function (data) {

    //console.log(accountNumbers);

    //socket.emit('syncContacts', accountNumbers);

    async.parallel(
        [
            function (callback) {
                var accountNumbers = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet(data[i].mobileNumber, function (success) {
                        if (success) {
                            accountNumbers.push({ewalletNumber: this.mobileNumber});
                            console.log(accountNumbers);
                        }
                    }.bind({mobileNumber: data[i].mobileNumber}));
                }
                callback(success, accountNumbers);
            }
        ],
        function (success, results) {
            console.log("results " + results.toString());
            socket.emit('syncContacts', results);
        });
});

function checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet(mobileNumber, callback) {
    var mobileNumber = mobileNumber.substr(1, mobileNumber.length);

    var query = "SELECT id FROM userEwallets WHERE ewalletNumber LIKE '%" + mobileNumber + "'";
    connection.query(query, function (err, results) {
        if (err) return callback(false);

        if (results.length === 0)
            return callback(false);
        else {
            return callback(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what socket library you're using, but perhaps the data sent with `.emit` should be a string?

Comment: @JoseRojas no, i dont get any error, code work fine, but when i push items to array i cant get that out of function

Comment: @Whothehellisthat problem is content of array which i get null to send

Comment: Can you post your checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet function?

Comment: @JoseRojas sure, post updated

Comment: @mahdipishguy, your problem is that the `if (success)` block happens *asynchronously*. This leads to your `socket.emit` call happening before the `if (success)` block. You need to call `socket.emit` asynchronously as well. See Michael Camden's answer below.

Comment: @dshapiro how can i do that? could you fix my code?

Comment: @mahdipishguy I posted an answer to show how I'd fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our code, it seems like `checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet` is an asynchronous event, which accepts a function callback. That would mean that the for-loop would execute, which would queue up executions to `checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet`. Immediately after the for-loop executes, console.log would correctly output the empty array `accountNumbers` and emit the event through the socket. Then the callback functions to each `checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet` execution would begin to execute, and log the `accountNumbers` array which now has data.

This can be solved in a few ways, but likely the easiest and most readable would be to create Promises, and act on the Promises when they resolve. Personally I like the 'when' promise library, but many libraries could help to solve this problem. https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#whensettle

Comment: @Michael Camden on `if` statement i get `[ { ewalletNumber: '7892331743' } ]` and after finishing that such as `for` i get `[]`

Comment: @Michael Camden My post updated, could you review again? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have no control over when the code inside the callback executes, and it ends up executing *after* you've already called `socket.emit`.

You can either a) use an async aggregator to call a callback for each successful mobile number and then, when all of those have finished, call the socket.emit call OR b) do something like what I did below. Alter your checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet function to accept and verify an array of mobile numbers, and pass the successful numbers to your callback function

Try the following:

```
socket.on('syncContacts', function (data) {
  var accountNumbers = [];
  var mobileNumbers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    mobileNumbers.push(data[i].mobileNumber);
  }

  checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet(mobileNumbers, function (successfulNumbers) {
      if (successfulNumbers.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < successfulNumbers.length; i++) {
              accountNumbers.push({ewalletNumber: successfulNumbers[i]});
          }
          socket.emit('syncContacts', accountNumbers);
      }
   }.bind({mobileNumbers: mobileNumbers}));
});
```

Comment: i want to send created array not post that every for loop statement

Comment: my post updated sir

Comment: I see your update. I'm not sure how async.parallel works. Will it call the array of callbacks followed by the single callback with the socket.emit? If so, that sounds like what you want.

Comment: could you update my `checkUserMobileNumberAsEwallet` function? i cant get result, result for send is empty too

Comment: Ha, someone just went through and downvoted the question and answers. What a cheeseball.

Comment: upvoted your post by me, i dont know went through and downvoted