# Nodejs How To Iterate With a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to iterate through an array of AD users and return some user information.
I've been looking for a few hours now, or more and haven't been quite able to get my head around the async nature of the activedirectory2 npm package.

I'm getting part of the result I need, however when iterating through the list of usernames, I'm only getting the first one printing out to console.

getADUser.js:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory2');
var config = require('../../conf/conf-ad.json')
var fileTime = require('./w32FiletimeToEpoch')
var moment = require('moment')
// Find user, return all
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);



var getADUser = function (sAMAccountName, opts) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ad.findUser(opts, sAMAccountName, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                // return;
            }
            if (!user) {
                console.log('User: ' + sAMAccountName + ' not found.');
            } else {
                if (user.userAccountControl == 514) {
                    user.userAccountControl = 'Disabled'
                } else {
                    user.userAccountControl = 'Active'
                }
                if (user.pwdLastSet) {
                    user.pwdLastSet = `${moment(fileTime(user.pwdLastSet))} - ${moment(fileTime(user.pwdLastSet)).fromNow()}`
                }
                if (user.lastLogonTimestamp) {
                    user.lastLogonTimestamp = `${moment(fileTime(user.lastLogonTimestamp))} - ${moment(fileTime(user.lastLogonTimestamp)).fromNow()}`
                }
                if (user.lastLogon) {
                    user.lastLogon = `${moment(fileTime(user.lastLogon))} - ${moment(fileTime(user.lastLogon)).fromNow()}`
                }
                // return;
                // return user.promise();
                // console.log(user)
                // test.push(user)
                resolve(JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
    })
}

module.exports = getADUser
```

checkADCompletions.js:

```
var checks = ['USERONE', 'USERTWO']

let opts = {
    attributes: ['sAMAccountName', 'userAccountControl']
};
let checkADCompletions = function (userList) {
    let data = []
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
            for (let i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
                getADUser(userList[i], opts)
                    .then(function (s) {
                        data.push(s)
                    }).then(function () {
                        resolve(data)
                    })
            }
        })
    })
}

checkADCompletions(checks).then(function (d) {
    console.log(d) \\ Only prints the first user details
})
```

Comment: Have you tried using `.map()` and `Promise.all()`?

Comment: I'm looking at using `.map()` now, but no idea about `Promise.all()`. I'm very new to async...

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806097/asynchronously-solution-to-check-data-from-database-kinds-of-loop-cluase/

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)! The `new Promise`s in your `checkADCompletions` function don't make any sense.

Comment: Cheers, I realise it doesn't make any sense now :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` like this:

```
let checkADCompletions = function (userList) {
    var promises = userList.map(function (user) {
        return getADUser(user, opts);
    })

    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

You are basically creating an array of promises and then executing them all concurrently.

And then use it like so:

```
checkADCompletions(checks)
.then(function (responses) {
    console.log(responses); // this will be an array
})
.catch(function (err) {
    // if any of the promises fail, it will enter here.
    // err will be the value of the rejected promise
})
```

[`Promise.all` will fail even if just one of the checked users fail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Promise.all_fail-fast_behaviour). So, you need to handle errors nicely, i.e. deal with *any* possible outcome of `ad.findUser`:

```
var getADUser = function (sAMAccountName, opts) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        ad.findUser(opts, sAMAccountName, function (err, user) {
            if (err || user == null) {
                console.log('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
                reject(err);
            }
            if (user.userAccountControl == 514) {
                user.userAccountControl = 'Disabled'
            } else {
                user.userAccountControl = 'Active'
            }
            if (user.pwdLastSet) {
                user.pwdLastSet = `${moment(fileTime(user.pwdLastSet))} - ${moment(fileTime(user.pwdLastSet)).fromNow()}`
            }
            if (user.lastLogonTimestamp) {
                user.lastLogonTimestamp = `${moment(fileTime(user.lastLogonTimestamp))} - ${moment(fileTime(user.lastLogonTimestamp)).fromNow()}`
            }
            if (user.lastLogon) {
                user.lastLogon = `${moment(fileTime(user.lastLogon))} - ${moment(fileTime(user.lastLogon)).fromNow()}`
            }
            resolve(user);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Makes much more sense now :)

Comment: I've obviously done something wrong because it just returns the first user multiple times. Will keep looking into it. Thanky ou!

Comment: Yeah, doing it that way runs the same user twice. Quite confusing indeed.

Comment: Oh, i think it's because the function should have `return getADUser(user, opts);` instead of `return getADUser(userList[i], opts);`. Sorry about that

Comment: Nah, I spotted that :)
Figured it out in the end though!! :D will post it later

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix would be to call `resolve` only when the for loop is finished.

```
// checkADCompletions.js
var checks = ['USERONE', 'USERTWO']

let opts = {
    attributes: ['sAMAccountName', 'userAccountControl']
};
let checkADCompletions = function (userList) {
    let data = []
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        for (let i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
            getADUser(userList[i], opts)
                .then(function (s) {
                    data.push(s)
                }).then(function () {
                    if (i === userList.length) {
                        resolve(data)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}

checkADCompletions(checks).then(function (d) {
    console.log(d)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

When you call `resolve`, you close out the Promise. You're initiating two Promises and then a `for` loop, and you call `resolve` inside the for loop. So the first user gets populated but the for loop does not continue because the Promise has finished executing. Move `resolve` outside of the loop and you should be good to go.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: No, moving `resolve` outside of the loop doesn't help anything at all. That'll only lead to `data` be empty instead of containing the only the first element.

Comment: Thanks for that @Bergi - This was something I had tried before and was wondering why I was getting that result.